# What's missing in oath resources doorkeeper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

I have `use_doorkeeper` in the routes file. When I visit `http://localhost:3021/oauth/applications`, I get:

```
Access to localhost was denied You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403
```

I cannot create a new client in `http://localhost:3021/oauth/applications/new` either.

What's missing?

This is my routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  use_doorkeeper

end
```

And this is my dookeeper initializer

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  # Change the ORM that doorkeeper will use (needs plugins)
  orm :active_record

  # This block will be called to check whether the resource owner is authenticated or not.
  resource_owner_authenticator do
    #raise "Please configure doorkeeper resource_owner_authenticator block located in #{__FILE__}"
    # Put your resource owner authentication logic here.
    # Example implementation:
    User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
    #current_user || User.authenticate!(:scope => :user)

  end
end
```

Comment: have you setup proper authorization per instruction in README?

Comment: Please provide routes file in question also provide doorkeeper.rb file

Comment: @kasperite Yes, I follow the basic steps from README. Those are the files. I don't know why i cannot see the form provider

Answer (score 2):

Check your log output in console.
If you see the following lines, then the problem might be in your doorkeeper.rb

```
Access to admin panel is forbidden due to Doorkeeper.configure.admin_authenticator being unconfigured.
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_admin! rendered or redirected
Completed 403 Forbidden in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

You have to uncomment this section:

```
  # admin_authenticator do
  #   # Put your admin authentication logic here.
  #   # Example implementation:
  #
  # if current_user
  #  head :forbidden unless current_user.admin?
  #   else
  #     redirect_to sign_in_url
  #   end
  # end
```

and remove `head :forbidden unless current_user.admin?` if you do not have an admin role set up.

And may be change redirect url